# find in Rails4 not behaving as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, find

I am upgrading my app from rails3 to rails4.
In friendship.controller.rb I have the line 
@friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
Surely this should identify the friend with an id corresponding to the value of
friend_id in the friendships table.
It returns a blank.  User.find(params[:id]) returns 340 which is the id of the friendship

Any ideas?

```
class FriendshipController < ApplicationController
  include ProfileHelper
  before_filter :setup_friends

  def create
    Friendship.request(@user, @friend)
    user = @user
    friend = @friend

    #MakeMailer.friend_request(user,friend).deliver

    flash[:notice] = "Friend request sent."
    redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
  end

  def accept
    if @user.requested_friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.accept(@friend, @user)
      flash[:notice] = "Friendship with #{@friend.login} accepted!"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "No friendship request from #{@friend.login}."
    end
    redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
  end

  def decline
    if @user.requested_friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.breakup(@user, @friend)
      flash[:notice] = "Friendship with #{@friend.login} declined"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "No friendship request from #{@friend.login}."
    end
    redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
  end

  def cancel
    if @user.pending_friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.breakup(@user, @friend)
      flash[:notice] = "Friendship request canceled."
    else
      flash[:notice] = "No request for friendship with #{@friend.login}"
    end
    redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
  end

  def delete
    if @user.friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.breakup(@user, @friend)
      flash[:notice] = "Friendship with #{@friend.login} deleted!"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "You aren't friends with #{@friend.login}"
    end
    redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
  end

  private

  def setup_friends
    @user = @current_user
    @friend = User.where(:id => params[:friend_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: can you post code for friendship controller ?

Comment: Done   I hope that helps

Comment: is your User and Friendship model related ? any association ? if yes than you can access directly by `current_user.friend.fields_of_friend_table` and no need of using @ for current_user if you are using devise. or you can use @user object if tables are related

Answer (score 0):

`User.find(id_of_user)` method takes id of user by default not any other attribute if you want to search by other parameter you can use `where` or `find_by_attribute`.

`User.where(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])` or

`User.find_by_friend_id(params[:friend_id)`

Comment: User.find_by_friend_id(params[:friend_id]) gives" undefined method `find_by_friend_id' "  User.where(:friend_id => params[:friend_id]) gives a null result